# Grid и flex Возможности

Tags: css, html5, flexbox, grid

Возник вопрос. У Яндекса есть галерея картинок [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&recent=7D&lr=30),

при изменении ширины картинки перестраиваются меняя при этом высоту рядов и количество ячеек, понятно что с js это все реализуется, возможно ли подобное реализовать на чистом css используя grid и flex?

Comment: да, это возможно.

Comment: если вы стилями ухитритесь получить ширину и высоту каждой картинки и подсчитать для каждого ряда суммарную ширину так, чтобы его высота не сильно отличалась от других рядов, то да =)

Comment: мнения разделились Grundy говорит что возможно Инквизитор думает как я)) Я тоже думаю что без js это сделать ни как, просто возник такой вопрос в голове, решил воспользоваться помощью зала=) Хотя конечно как это будет выглядеть по мнению Grundy в css для меня большой вопрос, лично я эту схему сообразить не могу.Спасибо ребят.